# JQuery Mobile data-rel=dialog not firing on iPhone or iPad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I found a question with my exact problem that nobody answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218707/jquery-mobile-data-rel-dialog-not-firing

I have a dialog that should open when the user presses on a button.  It works fine on ALL desktop browsers and Android browser.  It does NOT work in Safari on iPhone or iPad.  If you refresh the page on the iDevice, it works.

Here is my button:

```
<a href="#popup" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="slidedown">@Model.selectedDate.ToShortDateString()</a>
```

Here is my dialog:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="popup">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Production Date</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedSystem, "Select a date for System " + Model.selectedSystem)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.selectedSystem)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedDate, "Date:")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.selectedDate, new { type = "date" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Select</button>
}
</div>
```

Here is the page source for the rendered page:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <center>
            <a href="/Home/Main">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/company_header_logo_mobile.png" border="0" /></a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px">
        <center>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/Home/Main">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_home.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/Counts">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_prodcounts.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/Inventory">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_inventory.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/Vehicle">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_vehicle.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/SSAR">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_ssar.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/STAR">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_star.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
            <a href="/mobileDemo/EXECDASH">
                <img src="/mobileDemo/Images/menu_dashboard.png" style="width: 40px" border="0" /></a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px">
        <strong>Body Dashboard for System 1</strong>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 10px">
        <a href="#popup" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="right"
            data-transition="pop">11/7/2012</a>
        <hr />
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="/mobileDemo/ExecDash/BodyProd/1/11-07-2012">Production</a></li>
            <li><a href="/mobileDemo/ExecDash/BodyOEE?system=1&amp;date=11-07-2012">Body OEE</a></li>
            <li><a href="/mobileDemo/ExecDash/BodyDKS?system=1&amp;date=11-07-2012">Doukie-Seisan
                KPI</a></li>
            <li><a href="/mobileDemo/ExecDash/BodyDT?system=1&amp;date=11-07-2012">Down Time</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Production Date

Select a date for System 1
                
                Date:
                
            
            Select

Also worth noting, I am passing a parameter to the view.  The URL looks like this:

```
http://internal-server/mobileDemo/ExecDash/Body/1
```

Which goes to this when the dialog IS being displayed is:

```
http://internal-server/mobileDemo/ExecDash/Body/1#&ui-state=dialog
```

When is DOES NOT work (prior to refresh) on an iDevice, this is what is displayed when I hold down on the button and it gives me the OPEN/OPEN IN NEW TAB option:

```
http://internal-server/mobileDemo/ExecDash/Body/1#popup
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and for what it is worth... It doesn't work (unless you refresh page) in Chrome on the iPhone or iPad.

Comment: I edited my question and included the entire page source.  Also, when I use my desktop Safari with the useragent set to iPhone it works.  When I use Chrome with the useragent set to iPhone it does NOT.

Comment: I just captured the page source for the initial render (when dialog will not display) and after the refresh (when it does).  Used WinDiff and they are IDENTICAL.

Comment: For the record I never did get this corrected.  I simply restructured my app so that I didn't need to use the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I got your example working with some small tweak.

1. Created new project using VS2012 selected the mobile template.
2. Then in my Home/Index.cshtml I added your  tag i.e. the button that fires the popup.  Change the code to text be **@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()** since I didnt have your model.
3. I took your dialog  and pasted it in the _Layout.cshtml immediately after the closing  for the data-role="page"  see code below:

   ```
   <body>
   <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
       <div data-role="header">
           @if (IsSectionDefined("Header")) {
               @RenderSection("Header")
           } else {
               <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
               @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
           }
       </div>
       <div data-role="content">
           @RenderBody()
       </div>
   </div>

   <div data-role="dialog" id="popup">
       <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
           <h1>Production Date</h1>
       </div>
       <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">

       @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
           <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
               <label>hello world</label>

           </div>

           <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Select</button>
       }
       </div>
   </div>

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   ```

As you can see I also took out some of your code as I don't have your model, so I substituted my "hello world" label instead.  So why did I do it all that way?  Well, I tried to put the dialog in the index.cshtml BUT that meant the dialog HTML was getting output inside data-role="page" .  So it wasn't firing for me.    Once I moved it outside the data-role="page" div it worked.  Tested out on iPhone5 and it worked (without refresh). The one thing I did notice about your markup in this post was that you were missing one closing DIV.  So I'm not sure it was a copy/paste error or what.  Try my exact steps and you should see it working on and iDevice just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Daron.  I am using @RenderSection() in my _layout.cshtml in order to output any secondary pages such as this dialog.  Also, if I put in a more "vanilla" dialog page it does work.  I did have a copy/paste snafu and one closing DIV tag was missing.  My bad.

Comment: Correction: When I put in a more "vanilla" dialog page it does NOT work.